# Deleting an unwanted region of a 3D model

Tags: edit-mode

I have deleted the region of a 3D model around a circular region that I want to focus on, by deleting the Vertices (that was the obvious option in the context menu), but a lot of detail within the circle has also been deleted. How can I avoid this?

Grab 1 is the whole area in question, grab 2 shows the inverted selection (so the yellow is to be removed) and grab 3 shows the result after deleting Vertices. Clearly, I need to delete something else in the list or use some other method.

[image: Grab 1]

[image: Grab 2]

[image: Grab 3]

Comment: Thanks - As a newbe I will have to experiment to see what that all means

Comment: Sorry, see Answer ...

Answer (score 2):

Before you start to select anything, ensure **X-ray** Alt+Z is enabled.

[image]

Selection is happening for currently visible parts.
Dense mesh like yours has probably some vertices hidden behind others ... or in some cases density and distance from point of view is using some boundary that limits selection.

X-ray option let blender to make all vertices visible and selectable in  that depth direction.

Comment: Yes that worked, although I don’t understand why yet 

Comment: If this answered your question it's helpful to the site to accept the answer by clicking the answer's checkmark:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @JulianPerry a bit of edits ...